# Finding percentage proportion using specific columns and rows of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is the input data

```
Name  A B C D E F G Total
Ray   1 2 2 0 0 0 0  5
Tom   0 0 0 2 1 0 0  3
Sam   0 0 0 0 0 3 1  4
```

Below is the intended output

```
Name  A B C D E F G Total A:B:C      D:E    F:G
Ray   1 2 2 0 0 0 0  5    20:40:40   0:0    0:0
Tom   0 0 0 2 1 0 0  3    0:0:0      67:33  0:0
Sam   0 0 0 0 0 3 1  4    0:0:0      0:0    75:25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is create columns groups in list `cols` and then in loop divide selected columns by `sum`, replace `NaN`s, round and convert to integers, last join string:

```
#check columns names
print (df.columns.tolist())
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'Total']


cols = [('A','B','C'), ('D','E'), ('F','G')]

for c in cols:
    #for test
    print (c)
    print(df.loc[:, c])

    df[f'{":".join(c)}'] = (df.loc[:, c]
                              .div(df.loc[:, c].sum(axis=1), axis=0)
                              .fillna(0)
                              .mul(100)
                              .round()
                              .astype(int)
                              .astype(str)
                              .agg(':'.join, axis=1))

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  Total     A:B:C    D:E    F:G
0  1  2  2  0  0  0  0      5  20:40:40    0:0    0:0
1  0  0  0  2  1  0  0      3     0:0:0  67:33    0:0
2  0  0  0  0  0  3  1      4     0:0:0    0:0  75:25
```